# Using dialog_fselect to select file

Tags: c++, dialog, ncurses

I want to use `dialog_fselect` for selecting file in c++ console application. I wonder how I get the result path of `dialog_fselect`?
For example when I run:

```
dialog_fselect("Path", "", getmaxy(main_window)-10, getmaxx(main_window)-10);
```

How I could get the selected path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog_fselect` copies the result to [**`dialog_vars.input_result`**](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-_input_result):

> Certain widgets copy a result to this buffer.  If the pointer is  NULL,
>   or  if  the  length  is  insufficient  for  the result, then the dialog
>   library allocates a  buffer  which  is  large  enough,  and  sets  *DIALOG_VARS*.input_length.  Callers should check for this case if they have
>   supplied their own buffer.

(The capitialized *`DIALOG_VARS`* in the manual page refers to the type name rather than the actual variable of that type—see [*DATA STRUCTURES*](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h2-DATA-STRUCTURES)).